# Debugging with Zend Studio / Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, zend-studio

Is it possible to debug PHP scripts so that it keeps running until an expression is true?

For example, I want to know when $a becomes a certain value. I don't want to keep pressing step into and wait until the variable $a changes the value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set a breakpoint, right click on it and set a condition for it.

However, there are no global breakpoints, you must specify a location for every breakpoint you put. So, if you want to know where a value changes, you can't set any global conditions as they would be too CPU consuming.